# Access array of objects to display in React Native Text component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I’m having trouble accessing an array of objects in my JSON data to display in a React Native Text component.

**JSON data**

```
{
    "name": "Pizza Joint",
    "when": [{
        "day": ["Sat", "Sun"],
        "start_time": "11:00",
        "end_time": "23:00"
    }]
}
```

**Code**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.name}>{venue.name}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.time}>{venue.when[0].start_time}</Text>
</View>
```

This throws the error `Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'venue.when')` which I don't understand since `console.log(type of venue.when)` returns `object`.

How can I access the `when` object properties here?

**Additional notes**

I copied the app structure from [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/react-native-introduction/).

Here is `VenueList.js`:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var VenueDetail = require('./VenueDetail');

var {
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Component,
    ListView,
    TouchableHighlight,
    ActivityIndicatorIOS
   } = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        padding: 10
    },
    thumbnail: {
        width: 53,
        height: 81,
        marginRight: 10
    },
    rightContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        marginBottom: 8
    },
    author: {
        color: '#656565'
    },
    separator: {
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
    },
    listView: {
           backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
       },
   loading: {
       flex: 1,
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center'
   }
});

// var REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject:fiction';
var REQUEST_URL = 'http://apib.miniguide.es/wall/today';

class VenueList extends Component {

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
    console.log(this.state.dataSource);

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderVenue.bind(this)}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
    );
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loading}>
        <ActivityIndicatorIOS
          size='large'/>
          <Text>
            Loading venues...
          </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
      })
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
        isLoading: false
      });
    })
    .done();
  }

  renderVenue(venue) {
    console.log(venue);
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.showVenueDetail(venue)} underlayColor='#dddddd'>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
//              source={{uri: venue.images[0].url}}
              style={styles.thumbnail} />
            <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{venue.name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.author}>{venue.subtitle}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator} />
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = VenueList;
```

`console.log(venue)` produces the following format of data (I am simplifying output here for the purposes of the example):

```
{
    name: 'Pizza Joint',
        when: [{
            day: ['Sat', 'Sun'],
            start_time: '11:00',
            end_time: '23:00'
        }]
}
```

I notice the above is not JSON since the quotes on the keys have been stripped out.

Comment: is `{venue.when[0].start_time]}` a typo and did you write `{venue.when[0].start_time}` ?

Comment: yes, a typo, fixing sorry

Comment: The path access in the render code seems to be correct, there must be some problem with the way your passing the ```venue``` in render function. Try to console.log the venue object before rendering it.

Comment: How is `venue` exposed to your component ? Are you looping through a list fo venues ? Could you show what `console.log(venue)` outputs before rendering the View ?

Comment: do you set the initial state for the venue also, because if not it would be for start empty until you make a fetch request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The problem was the JSON data set that our API produces has some documents with another definition that delimit the data (e.g. first is document that indicates `featured`). So React was throwing an error on the first document, which lacked the properties I was attempting to access.

To fix this, I added ternary expressions to the React components to check for the existence of properties:

```
  renderVenue(venue) {
    console.log(venue);
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.showVenueDetail(venue)} underlayColor='#dddddd'>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={ 'images' in venue ? { uri: 'http://' + venue.images[0].url } : null}       
              style={styles.thumbnail} />
            <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{venue.name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.author}>{venue.subtitle}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.author}>{ 'when' in venue ? venue.when[0].start_date : null}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator} />
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Perhaps we should modify our API output.

In any event thanks for comments, they were helpful.